# Drupal, creating a view for Ubercart customers?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I want to customize the Ubercart customers list, displaying more fields enabling multiselection, actionsm etc..

I already have a view for drupal authenticated users, but I cannot display informations such as billing addresses from ubecart (or see orders)

Any tip ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Ubercart Views - http://drupal.org/project/uc_views ?

From the module page

> It also describes some of the Ubercart data tables to views, so you can create your own views, based on these data using the views_ui.